# No data returned from class method to PBO

Tags: oop, abap, pbo

I want to return record of table from abap method, which is field of class
but nothing is returned to the variable in PBO

definition in class

```
 data MS_ZORK_JG_SETTING type ZORK_JG_SETTING .

  methods GET_MS_ZORK_JG_SETTING
    returning
      value(MS_ZORK_JG_SETTING) type ZORK_JG_SETTING .
```

MS_ZORK_JG_SETTING is a data type which contains data from ZORK_JG_SETTING transparent table, filled properly using other method, so there is a correct data in this variable

in pbo of the screen i wanted to assign returned value to variable of the same type as returned

```
MODULE pbo_0102 OUTPUT.

DATA: wa_jg_setting TYPE zork_jg_setting.

  wa_jg_setting = go_bukrs_conf->get_ms_zork_jg_setting( ).

  MOVE-CORRESPONDING wa_jg_setting TO zork_jg_setting.


ENDMODULE.
```

But wa_jg_setting is empty. Tell me why and how to repair that?

Place of invoking screen

```
DATA: go_bukrs_conf TYPE REF TO zork_cl_scr_bukrs_conf.
CREATE OBJECT go_bukrs_conf
        EXPORTING
          pa_bukrs = '3020'.

      CALL SCREEN 102.
```

And get_ms_zork_jg_settings method. I am assigning a value of field to a formal parameter

```
  method GET_MS_ZORK_JG_SETTING.
    ms_zork_jg_setting = ms_zork_jg_setting."zwracana wartosc to pole/ atrybut
  endmethod.
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer such a question because you don't provide the code and you don't provide clues. You have to debug by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
ms_zork_jg_setting = ms_zork_jg_setting.
```

is useless, as you assign the value of the return parameter to itself.

Generally speaking, `var = var` is always non-sense.

Probably you want to do:

```
ms_zork_jg_setting = me->ms_zork_jg_setting.
```

Comment: Ok, dumb error, it works, thank you for your time and help, have a nice day!